# Using bibliometrix without a bib file

Tags: r

I have some bibliometric data in csv format that I'd like to analyse using `bibliometrix`. This wasn't downloaded via the Web of Science API but pulled together by someone else from Clarivate. It has some typical bib fields but also some atypical ones such as institutional affiliation ID codes. The data I want to analyse looks like this, I changed col headings to the appropriate bib codes:

```
df = data.frame(AU = 'Down, Andrea K.; Williams, Christopher D.; Wittenberg-Moerman, Regina',
            TI = 'Strategic syndication: is bad news shared in loan syndicates',
            SO = 'REVIEW OF ACCOUNTING STUDIES',
            C1 = '[Down, Andrea K.] Univ Toronto, Rotman Sch Management & UTSC Management, 105 St George St, St George, ON M5S 3E6, Canada; [Williams, Christopher D.; Down, Andrea K.] Univ Michigan, Ross Sch Business, 701 Tappan St, Ann Arbor, MI 48109 USA; [Wittenberg-Moerman, Regina] Univ Southern Calif, Marshall Sch Business, 3670 Trousdale Pkwy, Los Angeles, CA 90089 USA')
```

I can't use the package functions on it as it's missing the fields that come with a bib file. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you have the DOIs you could use rcrossref to create the bibtex from those

Comment: I do have DOIs. Do you mean using the `cr_cn` function from rcrossref?

Comment: yes just use the DOI coulmn as input argument and it should work

Comment: That seems to work, if you post as an answer I'll resolve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to recreate the bib file using the reference Doi,
and the library `rcrossref` s function `cr_cn`